# Why does Azure App Service Environment do the long deployment again when running the same ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I used the [quick start template 201-web-app-ase-ilb-create](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-web-app-ase-ilb-create) to **start** creating my ASE (in West Europe). I let it run overnight. At some point in time it timed out. The next morning - looking at the portal - the  deployment seemed to have succeeded. Before continuing adding the certificate for the ILB with the [quick start template 201-web-app-ase-ilb-configure-default-ssl](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-web-app-ase-ilb-configure-default-ssl) I reran the first template (just to be sure). Though no obvious change to the configuration is induced by the first template, a long deployment started again - probably for some more hours.

Comment: How is one supposed to use ARM templates for ASE deployment anyway - if deployments e.g. from Visual Studio run into timeouts: [ERROR] New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : The access token expiry UTC time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've also seen some really long running ASE deployments. usually with a fail at the end. I found two issues were common to these long deployments.

1. Most common was the fact i had forgotten the pre-requisite to have ports 454 and 455 open to the ASE subnet from all to all. this is what allows azure to do its magic and uses certs for security. if you're seeing over 2 hours for the deployment, make sure you've got this rule in place in your NSG.
2. I'd got a dependson block in the wrong place, which caused a long long wait.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this behaviour every time we deploy ASEs using ARM Templates. Even though the Front-End and Worker Pools, App Service Plans and App Services don't change, they still take a couple of hours. What we usually do is that we use Incremental deployments and have the ASE in a different template. This is not ideal, but we haven't found any other way to avoid long-running deployments.

HTHs

Comment: Running it in separate templates incrementally and not in the "big" one together with the other resources helped definetely. Another issue I had in my templates was, that by copying the subnet declaration from another place I had the ASE in a subnet with a NSG that only had a "rdp-rule" (like for a vm). I guess that made it running endlessly.

Comment: According to MS, ASE ARM deployment hasn't been optimised yet, thus, any ARM Template deployment will take hours, even when no changes are to be done. So the only workaround for this particular issue is to have multiple templates with Incremental deployment. It's a known issue, and hopefully, they fix it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the "access token expiry" when deploying from Visual Studio, the deployment can still complete in Azure even if Visual Studio tells you it has timed out. Basically, you have already sent the ARM template to Azure so the time out just means the polling info about the deployment in VS stops working.

Comment: a good reason to use an automated deployment tool, I'm thinking VSTS release management or Octopus Deploy off the top of my head.